# Changing properties class in custom component at designtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm writing simple component. What I want to achieve is that my MethodOptions will change in Object Inspector according to Method I choose.

Something like this:

[image: From DevExpress cxGrid]

So far I coded:

```
  TmyMethod = (cmFirst, cmSecond);

   TmyMethodOptions = class(TPersistent)    
    published
        property SomethingInBase: boolean;
   end;

   TmyMethodOptionsFirst = class(TmyMethodOptions)
    published
        property SomethingInFirst: boolean;
   end;

   TmyMethodOptionsSecond = class(TmyTMethodOptions)
    published
        property SomethingInSecond: boolean;
   end;

  TmyComponent = class(TComponent)
    private
      fMethod: TmyMethod;
      fMethodOptions: TmyMethodOptions;
      procedure ChangeMethod(const Value: TmyMethod);
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
    published
      property Method: TmyMethod read fMethod write ChangeMethod default cmFirst;
      property MethodOptions: TmyMethodOptions read fMethodOptions 
        write fMethodOptions;  
  end;

implementation

procedure TmyComponent.ChangeMethod(const Value: TmyMethod);
begin
  fMethod := Value;

  fMethodOptions.Free;
  // case...
  if Value = cmFirst then
    fMethodOptions := TmyMethodOptionsFirst.Create
  else
    fMethodOptions := TmyMethodOptionsSecond.Create;

//  fMethodOptions.Update;
end;

constructor TmyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fMethodOptions := TmyMethodOptions.Create;

  fMethod := cmFirst;
end;

destructor TmyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  fMethodOptions.Free;

  inherited;
end;
```

Of course it does <strike>almost</strike> nothing (except hanging IDE) and I don't have any starting point where to search the suitable knowledge to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think OI cares about the actual type of a property, it only displays the properties of the declared type (i.e. I believe this is not doable).

Comment: Include `paVolatileSubProperties` attribute when returning `GetAttributes` of your property editor.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly I believe that this the same technique the Developer Express implemented in their Quantum Grid component, for dynamically showing different properties for various field types in the grid.  There is an explanation of the mechanism here: [Technology of the QuantumGrid](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/dxram/archive/2009/09/19/technology-of-the-quantumgrid-source.aspx)

Comment: Your link requires login